# How to slove 'POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.'?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

i need to get coin analis from site. It is span with class 'speedometerSignal-DPgs-R4s sellColor-DPgs-R4s'. It should work, but  it isn't.

my code:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://ru.tradingview.com/symbols/DOTUSDT/technicals/", 'html'))
result = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"speedometerSignal-DPgs-R4s sellColor-DPgs-R4s"})

for res in result:
    print(res.decode_contents().strip())
```

and error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrey/PycharmProjects/pfkegf/analis.py", line 4, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://ru.tradingview.com/symbols/DOTUSDT/technicals/", 'html').json())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 522, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1285, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.
```

help please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're passing `'html'` to `urllib2.urlopen` - are you certain you don't instead want to pass it to `BeautifulSoup`, in other words, move the `)` one position over?

Comment: ok it is works, but when i print it i have output like '[]'. How to get word

Comment: This particular site is "dynamic", meaning the content is generated dynamically in the browser (by React in this case). When you do a simple web request you don't get the content that you see in the browser. You need to use  something like **selenium** to render it on your system, and then srape.

Comment: can you help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need to render it before scraping. This can be done with selenium web driver, but will require some setup first.

1. Install selenium

```
pip install selenium
```

2. Install the driver for your browser. This is a binary, specific for your OS and the browser. The chrome web driver for instance can be downloaded at https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
3. Provide the path to the installed web driver to selenium in your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

web_driver = webdriver.Chrome(<path-to-your-installed-web-driver>)

url = "https://ru.tradingview.com/symbols/DOTUSDT/technicals/"

# initiate scrape of website page data
web_driver.get(url)

# get the (dynamically generated) content
content = web_driver.page_source

# use soup to make page content easily searchable
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

spans = soup.findAll('span', {'class':'speedometerSignal-DPgs-R4s sellColor-DPgs-R4s'})

for span in spans:
    print(span.text)
```

At the time of this writing it prints:

```
Продавать
Активно продавать
```

Comment: thank you a lot. You are the best!

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://ru.tradingview.com/symbols/DOTUSDT/technicals/", 'html').read())
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("https://ru.tradingview.com/symbols/DOTUSDT/technicals/").read() , 'lxml')
result = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"speedometerSignal-DPgs-R4s sellColor-DPgs-R4s"})

print(result)

Comment: in output i get: []

Comment: how to get word